# Query ORDER BY dinâmica a partir da seleção de uma comboBox

Tags: java, sql, swing, jtable

Estou a desenvolver uma aplicação em *java* que faz a gestão de uma base de dados. Esta aplicação primariamente efectua um `SELECT` a base de dados, submetendo depois o `ResultSet` para uma tabela editável.

Tentei adicionar uma `comboBox` para o utilizador selecionar a ordem na qual quer listar os dados, mas o segmento de código que escrevi para este efeito não está a funcionar.

A minha dúvida é se existe alguma forma de contornar este problema e fazer algum tipo de concatenação de `strings` e variáveis para que o parâmetro do `ORDER BY` seja dinâmico e dependente do que o utilizador escolher .

```
else if (Item == 1)
{ /* Computer List) */
    comboBoxOrderBy.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "computer_id", "cpu_model",
        "cpu_clock", "ram", "hdd", "os", "archit", "computer_name", "computer_type",
    "computer_brand", "computer_model", "serial_number", "status" }));
    comboBoxOrderBy.addActionListener(
    new ActionListener()
    { /*
        * ACÇAO DA CAIXA
        * ORDER BY
        */
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0)
        {
            String teste = (String)comboBoxOrderBy.getSelectedItem();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frmInventoryDatabaseManager, teste);
            try
            {
                /*
                * BEGINING OF DATABASE REQUEST
                */
                Connection lig = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:mysql://localhost/inventorydb", "root", "");
                PreparedStatement inst = lig.prepareStatement(
                "SELECT computer_id, cpu_model, cpu_clock, ram, hdd, "
                + "os, archit, computer_name, computer_type, computer_brand, "
                + "computer_model, serial_number, status FROM computerlist ORDER BY ? ASC");
                inst.setString(1, teste);
                ResultSet rs = inst.executeQuery();
                table1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));
                lig.close();
                /*
                * END OF DATABASE REQUEST
                * SERVICES
                */
            }
            catch (SQLException e1)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frmInventoryDatabaseManager,
                "Impossivel ligar á base de dados: "
                + e1.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Você quer que, ao se alterar a opção no combobox, a tabela seja alterada de acordo com a opção selecionada? E o que você quer dizer com *não estar a funcionar*?

Comment: Assim que a selecção da tabela é feita , , os dados dentro da tabela nao se ordenam conforme a selecção da combobox (nada acontece), neste caso , cada ação supostamente  remete para um parâmetro ORDER BY diferente, penso que o problema seja a instrução não estar bem feita,  já testei fazer uma query ORDER BY normal especificando o campo pretendido e funciona perfeitamente.

Comment: Uma pergunta, a tabela já está populada antes da seleção do combobox, e isso ai só altera a ordem dos elementos dela?

Comment: Exato , a tabela foi populada anteriormente por meio de uma seleção de outra combobox na qual o utilizador escolhe que table a presentar ;  usei depois um método importado que permite popular a tabela  de acordo a natureza e disposição das tabelas da base de dados  table1.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

Comment: Pra que então consultar o banco de novo só pra ordenar, se os dados já estão ali? Se você fizer `suaTable.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true)`, as colunas já serão ordenáveis, ao se clicar no cabeçalho. Lembrando que pra funcionar, seu TableModel precisa ter as classes das colunas definidas em `getColumnClass`, caso não esteja usando `DefaultTableModel`. Teste ai.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda , essa simples função me fez chegar ao pretendido

Comment: Que bom :) Quer que transforme como resposta?

Comment: Sim pode transformar

Answer (score 1):

Como o objetivo é ordenar a tabela de acordo com a coluna, basta ativar o `rowSorter`, através do comando:

```
suaTable.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
```

Com isso, as colunas se tornam "organizáveis". Lembrando que, caso use um `TableModel` próprio, é necessário identificar os tipos de dados de cada coluna através do método `getColumnClass` para que funcione corretamente(caso alguma coluna seja de algum tipo de classe criada por você).